# Faster/lazier way to evenly and randomly split m*n into n group (each has m elements) in python

Tags: python, random, generator, permutation, lazy-sequences

I want to split `m*n` elements (e.g., 1, 2, ..., `m*n`) into `n` group randomly and evenly such that each group has `m` random elements. Each group will process `k` (`k>=1`) elements at one time from its own group and *at the same speed* (via some synchronization mechanism), until all group has processed all their own elements. Actually each group is in an independent process/thread.

I use `numpy.random.choice(m*n, m*n, replace=False)` to generate the permutation first, and then index the permuted result from each group.

The problem is that when `m*n` is very large (e.g., `>=1e8`), the speed is very slow (tens of seconds or minutes).

Is there any faster/lazier way to do this? I think maybe this can be done in a lazier way, which is not generating the permuted result in the first time, but generate a generator first, and in each group, generate k elements at each time, and its effect should be identical to the method I currently use. But I don't know how to achieve this lazy way. And I am not sure whether this can be implemented actually.

Comment: Your goal appears to be to generate a permutation of N items by multiple threads in parallel.  The following may point you in the right direction: https://github.com/lorenzhs/sampling .  Also, generating a permutation is equivalent to generating N exponential variates and sorting them (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.00227.pdf).  If that helped you find an answer, you can post it.

Comment: @PeterO. Thanks! It seems promising! I will have a try first.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  If so you should post that solution as an answer.

Comment: @PeterO. I haven't found a satisfying solution, but I comprised and implement a sequence server to generate one number at each time using fisher-yates algorithm, and put the generated number into `n` queue for the `n` processes to get from.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a generator that will progressively shuffle (a copy of) the list and lazily yield distinct groups:

```
import random
def rndGroups(A,size):
    A = A.copy()                    # work on a copy (if needed)
    p = len(A)                      # target position of random item
    for _ in range(0,len(A),size):  # work in chunks of group size
        for _ in range(size):       # Create one group 
            i = random.randrange(p) # random index in remaining items
            p -= 1                  # update randomized position
            A[i],A[p] = A[p],A[i]   # swap items
        yield A[p:p+size]           # return shuffled sub-range
```

Output:

```
A  = list(range(100))
iG = iter(rndGroups(A,10)) # 10 groups of 10 items
s  = set()                 # set to validate uniqueness
for _ in range(10):  # 10 groups
    g = next(iG)     # get the next group from generator
    s.update(g)      # to check that all items are distinct
    print(g)
print(len(s))        # must get 100 distinct values from groups

[87, 19, 85, 90, 35, 55, 86, 58, 96, 68]
[38, 92, 93, 78, 39, 62, 43, 20, 66, 44]
[34, 75, 72, 50, 42, 52, 60, 81, 80, 41]
[13, 14, 83, 28, 53, 5, 94, 67, 79, 95]
[9, 33, 0, 76, 4, 23, 2, 3, 32, 65]
[61, 24, 31, 77, 36, 40, 47, 49, 7, 97]
[63, 15, 29, 25, 11, 82, 71, 89, 91, 30]
[12, 22, 99, 37, 73, 69, 45, 1, 88, 51]
[74, 70, 98, 26, 59, 6, 64, 46, 27, 21]
[48, 17, 18, 8, 54, 10, 57, 84, 16, 56]
100
```

*This will take just as long as pre-shuffling the list (if not longer) but it will let you start/feed threads as you go, thus augmenting the parallelism*